# Model Binding returns null when string is posted instead of array

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I have a .Net Core 3 Api when I am using Netonsoft to perform model binding.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options => { options.AllowSynchronousIO = true; });
        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => { options.AllowSynchronousIO = true; });
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddMvcCore().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0).AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddCheck<ApiHealthCheck>("api");

    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
    }
}
```

In Api I am expecting a model similar to:

```
public class Family
{
    public Member Member1 { get; set; }
    public Member Member2 { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public List<string> LastNames { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I post the following Json, Model binding gives me a family object with values taken from Json:

```
{
    "member1": {
        "firstName": "john",
        "lastNames": [
            "wick"
        ]
    },
    "member2": {
        "firstName": "Rich",
        "lastNames": null
    }
}
```

However when I post the following Json (lastnames value is string instead of an array):

```
{
    "member1": {
        "firstName": "john",
        "lastNames": "wick"
    },
    "member2": {
        "firstName": "Rich"
    }
}
```

I expect to get a Family object with Member1, and Member2 having only firstname.

But I am getting null (No Family is found in model received).

Should this behavior be expected? and how to tell Newtonsoft to ignore only lastnames instead of the whole model?

Comment: You can look into writing a custom JsonConverter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own custom converter for ignore it. Solution is:

First declare your custom Resolver classes.

```cs
        class IgnoreNullList : DefaultContractResolver
        {
            protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
            {
                JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
                if (objectType == typeof(List<string>))
                {
                    contract.Converter = new MyNullIgnorer();
                }

                return contract;
            }
        }

    internal class MyNullIgnorer : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {

        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
                List<string> items = token.ToObject<List<string>>();
                return items;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And in your code convert your object with custom converter.

```cs
....

            var setting = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ContractResolver = new IgnoreNullList()
            };

var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Family>(yourJsonString, setting);
```